# What did the rival mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

the United States was tracking a “specific” and “credible” threat at the airport from the Islamic State affiliate in Afghanistan, which has carried out dozens of attacks in recent years and is a **rival** of the Taliban.

What did the rival mean?

1. a person, group, etc. competing with others for the same thing or in the same area
2. to be as good, clever, beautiful, etc. as someone or **something else**

how to know which meaning is that I'm searching for? Sometimes there are just many meanings of the same word. And put each of them in the sentence are both make sense. So, can you tell me a concrete way to avoid choosing wrong meaning?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary? What did you find? What are you still confused about?

Comment: Yeah, the above were cited from dictionary.

Comment: So, did they mean that "threat" is as horrible as Taliban or "threat" are competing for some resource in Afghanistan with Taliban? Because there is **something else** so I am confused. I guess sometimes there can be a satirize as well, but I actually don't know how the satirize in English work, though. In Chinese, sometime "Yeah, so kind of you." can mean "wow why have you did this to me? That was unpalatable".

Comment: One of those definitions is a noun, and the other is a verb. Which is "rival" in your sentence?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me the part of speech can help understanding which definition the words were having. But may I ask you another question? According to the dictionary, rival sometimes can mean competing for something bad, too. How can I know what they are competing for when they didn't tell? Like in this sentence, I really can't understand weather they are competing for resources or bad reputation.

Comment: It's a noun, so they are competing for resources, in this case, control of land. The verbal meaning is not about competition. It only means they're similar in some way. To compare the Islamic State and Taliban with "rival" in the second meaning, you might say, "The Taliban rival the Islamic State in ruthlessness." This sentence only means *they're similarly ruthless*, NOT that they're both trying to win some ruthlessness competition.

Comment: Your explanation really helps a lot, thank you.

Comment: There isn't enough information in the sentence. to say for certain, but I read it as the group wants to control the same areas and resources that the Taliban does.

Answer (score 1):

It's a noun, so they are competing for resources, in this case, control of land. The verbal meaning is not about competition. It only means they're similar in some way. To compare the Islamic State and Taliban with "rival" in the second meaning, you might say, "The Taliban rival the Islamic State in ruthlessness." This sentence only means they're similarly ruthless, NOT that they're both trying to win some ruthlessness competition.

Comment: Answer was posted as a comment.